# Negate ActiveRecord query scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have a slightly complicated scope on a model

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :active,       -> { where(inactive: false) }
  scope :groups,       -> { where(contact_type: 2308) }
  scope :group_search, -> (query) do
    active.groups.where("last_name LIKE '%' + ? + '%'", query)
  end
end
```

For testing purposes, I want to make sure that **all `Contacts` *not* returned by `group_search`** are excluded for the right reasons.

But to get that list, I have to load

```
Contact.all - Contact.group_search('query')
```

which runs two queries, returns an `Array` instead of a `Relation`, and is slower than I'd like.

And since I'm testing the `group_search` scope, writing *another* scope that is its negative would kind of spoil the point. I'd rather just do something like:

```
Contact.merge.not(Contact.group_search('query'))
```

to generate the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM contacts 
WHERE NOT (contact_type = 2308 AND inactive = 0 AND last_name LIKE '%' + ? + '%')
```

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Slightly faster way would be: `Contact.where.not(id: Contact.group_search('query').pluck(:id))`. Still two queries, but will return a relation and will drastically limit one of the queries. AFAIK, there is no way to negate scope atm.

Comment: Yeah... also the query itself could potentially get very large... this table has something to the order of 100k records, and the IDs are UUIDs, so if I want "not (something very common)" I could be looking at megabytes just for the query string.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To negate an scope you can use:

```
Contact.where.not(id: Contact.group_search('query'))
```

This is not the same as using `pluck` (proposed in one of the comments):

```
Contact.where.not(id: Contact.group_search('query').pluck(:id))
```

Without the `pluck`, it produces one query (with two selects):

```
SELECT  `contacts`.* FROM `contacts` WHERE `contacts`.`id` NOT IN (SELECT `contacts`.`id` FROM `contacts` WHERE `contacts`.`group_search` = 'query')
```

With the `pluck`, it produces two independent queries:

```
SELECT `contacts`.`id` FROM `contacts` WHERE `contacts`.`group_search` = 'query'
SELECT  `contacts`.* FROM `contacts` WHERE `contacts`.`id` NOT IN (1, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 329, 330, 331, 332, 333, 334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339, 340, 341, 342, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 360, 361)
```

When querying many records, the first one is way more efficient. Of course `Contact.where.not(group_search: 'query')` is more efficient as it produces one query with one select (but this may be not possible in some cases):

```
SELECT `contacts`.`id` FROM `contacts` WHERE `contacts`.`group_search` != 'query'
```

Comment: Yeah, the [comments on the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527819/negate-activerecord-query-scope/53498042#comment51017535_31527819) suggested this too, but it's still two queries, and potentially a very large set of IDs to exclude.

Comment: This is not exactly the same as the one you are linking which uses pluck. This only produces one query, which is way more efficient. I updated the answer to include this. ;)

Comment: This is actually way better - but is it available to Rails 4.x?

Comment: Sure! It was introduced in Rails 4.0

Comment: This is great! I see you've simplified my `group_search` scope for your SQL, but most of it still works. Unfortunately, `Contact.where.not.group_search('query')` _doesn't_ work, as `not` expects at least one argument; and `Contact.where.not(group_search: 'query')` (as would have produced that SQL) doesn't match my original scope... and I needed something that would negate it without rewriting it.

Comment: @AnaMaríaMartínezGómez, didn't know about the approach to be working in such fashion, thank you a lot for sharing)

Comment: @PJSCopeland true, the query was wrong (updated). I simplified a bit the query to make it easy to understand (I did it in all the SQL). In your case, the most efficient would be another scope with `active.groups.where.not("last_name LIKE '%' + ? + '%'", query)`, but using the `:id` is an elegant solution (without rewriting anything) at a not high performance cost. ;)

Comment: Again though, this is specifically for testing `#group_search`. Rewriting it in a negative form will not test `#group_search` itself, just something like it. And it's supposed to negate the _entire_ scope - so it should include Contacts that are not `active` or not `groups` _as well._

Comment: TIL: that scopes like this will assume the subquery `IN`/`NOT IN` without the `pluck`, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 13):

I think what you are looking for is called negating the scope, you can use `where_values` (or `where_values_hash` in Rails >= 5):

```
conditions = Contact.group_search('query').where_values
@contacts = Contact.where.not(conditions.reduce(:and))
```

For this solution to work in Rails 4.x, you should provide values in the scope as arrays:

```
scope :groups, -> { where(contact_type: [2308]) }
```

I'v also found a neat [general implementation for negating the scopes](https://content.pivotal.io/blog/logically-negating-an-activerecord-scope), you may also find it interesting.

Comment: Thanks! But why should I use arrays?

Comment: This looks like it should work perfectly - unfortunately it looks like SQL Server is being a bitch about this: `TinyTds::Error: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'.: EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [contact].* FROM [contact] WHERE (NOT ([contact].[contact_type] = 2308 AND [contact].[inactive] = 0 AND N''last_name LIKE ''''%query%''''''))'`

Comment: @Patrick: I don't know why, but Rails is not binding arguments if values are not provided as arrays, it's seems to be a known bug that appeared in Rails 4.2. Which version do you use?

Comment: Ah, I'm stuck using 4.1, that would be why.

Comment: Original link redirects to pivotal.com I think this is new location https://content.pivotal.io/blog/logically-negating-an-activerecord-scope

Comment: @dft it might be this link here i believe:
https://content.pivotal.io/blog/logically-negating-an-activerecord-scope

Comment: `where_values` has been removed in Rails 5. `where_values_hash` can be used instead

Answer (score 6):

In Rails 6, negative scopes are added on the enum values.

You can use it like this:

```
Contact.not_active
Contact.not_groups
Contact.not_group_search
```

Related [pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/35381)

Comment: Although that is true for enum generated scopes, it does not work for scopes you declare yourself as in the question.