# How to chain class methods together in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got this in my Rails 5 model:

```
def self.payable
  open.where.not(:delivery_status => "draft")
end

def self.draft
  where(:delivery_status => "draft")
end

def self.open
  where(:payment_status => "open")
end
```

Is there a more elegant way to write the first method?

It would be great to chain the `open` and `draft` methods together like this:

```
def self.payable
  open.not(:draft)
end
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work.

Comment: [may be of help](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31527819/3444240)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To chain negated queries you can use this trick:

```
def self.payable
  open.where.not(id: draft)
end
```

Another alternative if you don't care if an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object is returned is using `-`, which returns an `Array`:

```
def self.payable
  open - draft
end
```

I would personally use `scope`s instead of class methods for queries: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes. So:

```
scope :draft, -> { where(:delivery_status => "draft") }
scope :open, -> { where(:payment_status => "open") }
scope :payable, -> { open.where.not(id: draft) }
```

Comment: "This is exactly the same as defining a class method, and which you use is a matter of personal preference". From the documentation you linked

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use scopes?

```
scope :payable, -> { open.where.not(:delivery_status => "draft") }
```

You can use this like that

```
YouModel.payable
```