# How to do the opposite for merge in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently, I have two models

```
class Project
   has_one: user

end

class User
   # Attributes
   # active: Boolean
   # under_18: Boolean

   scope :can_work, -> { where(active: true, under_18: false) }
end
```

Querying code

```
Project.all.joins(:user).merge(User.can_work)
```

Currently, the above code is working but if possible I want to do the opposite

```
Project.all.joins(:user).merge(User.can_work, false) # not working obviously, just an example of my thought
```

I know it is possible to create another scope like

```
User.can_not_work #
```

but I want to negate the scope in the query, instead of creating another scope

Edit:

I'm adding the truth table, just in case if anyone is confused on why I don't use the negative scope

```
active |  under_18
------------------
   T        T        = F
   T        F        = T   (I know its a bit weird It should just be F but its the condition)
   F        T        = F
   F        F        = F
```

I'm not sure how to do the negative scope for the above logic. Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527819/negate-activerecord-query-scope

Comment: To be honest, defining a scope: `User.cannot_work` is probably going to be a good idea anyway!... I know this is a lazy answer to your question, but I'd just stick to that.

Comment: @TomLord yeah you are right, but i walk through my truth table, some of the condition might not work properly if I use the negative scope, or maybe my knowledge might be limited on defining the proper negative scope.

Comment: @TomLord i added the truth table any idea how to carve out the logic for the scope?

Comment: The negated scope, just written in plain SQL, is: `where('active = false OR under_18 = true')`.

Comment: My point was not so much "you can't negate the scope!", but rather, "this looks like a darn useful scope to have anyway! I bet you'll end up using it in a dozen different places. So rather than worrying about how to correctly negate it all over the place, why not just clearly define it in the `User` class?"

Answer (score 2):

On Rails 6.1 you can use [invert_where](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-invert_where)

```
Project.all.joins(:user).merge(User.can_work.invert_where)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, this doesnt work it will only work on where clause

Comment: my rails version is still 6.0.0, im guessing that's the case.

Comment: The `invert_where` method was added in Rails 7.0. Cf https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7-0-stable/activerecord/CHANGELOG.md